# Html video tag on loop in IE/Edge consumes endless bandwidth?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

For any larger H.264 MP4 video, as low as 10MB in sizes, IE and Edge will download the entire video over and over on each play. If the video tag is set to loop it will continuously use up bandwidth! .. at 2MB/sec for 1080p videos this can really become a problem.. Is there any workaround?

Reproduced on different devices, Win7 through 10. Has been a known bug for years and it is still not fixed..

Reproduced here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NpgD5/853/

```
<video loop autobuffer controls autoplay>
    <source id="mp4" src="http://teleport.blob.core.windows.net/video/fall1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

or

http://www.teleport.nu/feed/4ts588oao0kmp7rsiaqtmgb5ownoj80soxajkha1kka?playMode=livetimelapse

or

http://www.teleport.nu/feed/mthayes?playMode=livetimelapse

Note the red progress bar, once the video reaches the end, there is a pause which should not occur, this is when the browser re-buffers the same file over again. Make sure to view the 720p or 1080p videos, as this does not happen for small files.

May depend on the server, these are stored in Azure Blob storage.

This does not occur in other browsers.

Please fix!

**UPDATE:**

Just tried the jsfiddle link on a Surface Pro 3, Windows 10 fully updated, Edge 25.10586.0.0. Occurs when connected to either Ethernet or WiFi.

Screenshot : http://1drv.ms/1QijcUb

Using Windows Resource Manager as shown in the screenshot. Note the bandwidth bumps, each one represents the video tag looping.

Can also see repeat requests in Fiddler. Here are the request headers, always the same:

```
GET /video/fall1.mp4 HTTP/1.1
If-Unmodified-Since: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 02:36:25 GMT
If-Match: "0x8CFA0A874DB3B28"
Range: bytes=0-40618253
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
Referer: http://fiddle.jshell.net/NpgD5/853/show/
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
Accept-Language: en-CA,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: teleport.blob.core.windows.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And the response, same except timestamp and x-msrequest-id changes:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Length: 40618254
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-40618253/40618254
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Dec 2012 02:36:25 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0x8CFA0A874DB3B28"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: cdd2d3a4-0001-002d-680d-2e297b000000
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-lease-state: available
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Date: Thu, 03 Dec 2015 20:56:53 GMT
```

Comment: Checking each link in Edge 25, I don't see any requesting the video after each play. Which version of Edge are you testing, and how are you confirming the subsequent requests?

Comment: Reproduced it again, see info above. Perhaps it's location related? Different cache/network conditions? Are your headers the same?

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this? I've been able to reproduce it on many different devices and locations/ISPs..

Comment: Has it reproduced on *every* device you've tested? Or only on some?

Comment: Must be rare, but I've been seeing this for some time now. Seems like IE/Edge will not cache the video. Could even be the network card, or even video driver.

It occurs every time on the Surface Pro 3 with latest updates. Does not occur on a ThinkPad with same bits. Comes and goes on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with latest IE. Reproduced yesterday, then rebooted and it is not anymore.

No matter what I try on the Surface Pro 3 it will not fix it. Including creating a new local windows account. Making sure there is lots of free space. Clearing temporary files.